# How do you include electron binary while using python + selenium for testing

Tags: python, selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python and selenium to test an electron app. When the app opens through selenium though, it seems it is missing electron because all of the i18n replacements didn't take place. If I open the app manually, then everything works fine. We are speculating that somehow electron isn't loading up correctly. Does anyone know how to add an electron binary to chrome driver options somehow? This is what I have below

```
from selenium import webdriver as app
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Users/eeee/AppData/Local/Programs/folder/app.exe"
caps = app.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:chromeOptions'] = {'binary': "./node_modules/.bin/electron"}

driver = app.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, options=options)  # start

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it has to do with the fact that on a windows system the working directory changes.

So you need to set the current working directory to the same folder where the exe is living. You can do with with `Popen` or with some work within `selenium`, but its not native in selenium

I tested with slack:

```
app_path=\AppData\Local\slack\app-4.20.0\slack.exe
app_cwd=\AppData\Local\slack\app-4.20.0
```